# Showing independence

Tags: self-study, independence

$X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are independent, chi-square distributed random variables. I've managed to show that $Z=X_{1}+X_{2}$ is independent of $\frac{X_{1}}{Z}$. How do I conclude then that $Z=X_{1}+X_{2}$ is independent of $(\frac{X_{1}}{Z},\frac{X_{2}}{Z})$?

Comment: Are you sure these assertions are true?

Comment: i doubt it.  Can you show me why?

Comment: Is it due to the fact that $X_{2} = Z - X_{1}$?

Comment: I don't see why Z would be independent of X1/Z since Z and X1 are clearly dependent and Z is negatively correlated to 1/Z. Before you try to show that Z is independent of X2/Z how did you manage to show Z and X1/Z are independent?

Comment: The joint pdf of $Z$ and $U_{1}=X_{1}/Z$ factors.

Comment: Okay so then if I assume you that you worked that out for the chi square distributions then as you pointed out since X2=Z-X1 X2/Z=1-X1/Z which is just a constant minus a random variable that is independent of Z and hence is independent of Z.

Comment: Are you wanting to show that $Z = X_1+X_2$, $U = X_1/Z$ and $V= X_2/Z$ are three independent random variables, that is, $f_{Z,U,V}(z,u,v) = f_Z(z)f_U(u)f_V(v)$ or that $Z$ is independent of the pair $(U,V)$, that is, $f_{Z,U,V}(z,u,v) = f_Z(z)f_{U,V}(u,v)$ since $U$ and $V$ are not independent random variables?  Indeed, since $U+V = 1$, $f_{U,V}(u,v)$ is not a joint density but rather a _line_ density.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Re: independence of $Z$ and $X_1/Z$ in the case of _exponential_ random variables (a special case of chi-square random variables), see Didier Piau's comment on [this answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/204716/15941) on math.SE

Comment: @Dilip : Yes, I just want to show that Z and (U, V) are independent.

Comment: Thanks guys.  It is unusual but I realize it possible.

Answer (score 6):

We have 
$$\left(\frac{X_1}Z,\frac{X_2}Z\right)=\left(\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2},\frac{X_2}{X_1+X_2}\right)=(0,1)+\left(\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2},-\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}\right),$$
hence you just have to show that $Z$ is independent of $\frac{X_1}Z(1,-1)$, which is the case by what you showed.